# virtual hosts DocumentRoot not being changed

Tags: apache, dns

Don't think my virtualhost is working correctly. This is what I have inside of httpd.conf...it is the last thing in the file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testing
ServerName testing.aa.local
</VirtualHost>
```

In my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 testing.aa.local
```

Now when I go to testing.aa.local it shows the index page of the root of the site. In httpd.conf the document root is `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. It appears it is taking that document root and not the VirtualHost documentroot. When I restart httpd there are no errors. When I say httpd -S it says:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -S 
VirtualHost configuration: wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          aa.local (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
*:*                    aa.local (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:974)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server testing.aa.local (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1031)
         port 80 namevhost testing.aa.local (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1031) Syntax OK
```

Anyone understand why when I go to testing.aa.local it is showing me the index page of /var/www/html rather than /var/www/html/testing? Again, /var/www/html is defined as the httpd.conf file as the DocumentRoot but later on I declare the virtualhost container and so I thought it should overwrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my httpd.conf file there are a virtualhost container all ready. I commented it out and it now works.

Comment: I am afraid I am not able to get any response from the default "var/www/html" root folder too. Like I am stuck. I included the mod_jk.conf in httpd.conf too for moving the document. Let alone my new document root , the default one is also showing page not found.